# Javascript metronome: HTML5 inside animation creating strange echo

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm making a simple Raphael-powered Javascript metronome. My trouble is with the click sound, which strangely starts firing twice after about a dozen clicks. I'm currently using the  tag, but I have the same problem when using SoundManager2.

I've got it all [on a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chriswilsondc/wDwsW/1/), and here is the important part:

```
<audio id="tick" src="http://experimentsinform.com/media/audio/tick.wav"></audio>

<script>
    var paper = Raphael("canvas", 300, 300);

    function tick() {        
        document.getElementById("tick").play();
    }

    var metronome = function(x, y, l) {
         //draw metronome. See fiddle            
         var mn = paper.set(stick, vertex, weight).attr("transform", "R-20 " + x + "," + y);

         Raphael.easing_formulas.sinoid = function(n) { return Math.sin(Math.PI * n / 2) };

         return {
             start: function(tempo, sound) {
                 var interval = 120000 / tempo;            
                 var ticktock = Raphael.animation({
                     "50%": { transform:"R20 " + x + "," + y, easing: "sinoid", callback: function() { sound(); }},
                     "100%": { transform:"R-20 " + x + "," + y, easing: "sinoid", callback: function() { sound(); }}
                 }, interval);

              mn.animate(ticktock.repeat(Infinity));
        },
        stop: function() {
            mn.stop();
            mn.attr("transform", "R-20 " + x + "," + y);
        }
    };    
};

var m = metronome(150, 275, 250);
m.start(120, tick);

</script>
```

If you let it tick about 20 times in Chrome, you start getting a double-click sound. Anyone have any idea why? I kept the mp3 sound effect to 30ms or so.

Thank you!

Comment: I can't reproduce this in chrome 26.0.1410.43m which version are you seeing this in?  Chrome seems to have had quite a few audio bugs recently (I got bitten by one just like this a few months ago).

Comment: Ah now I get it (took more like 60 ticks for me)... Haven't used Raphael before.  But if I were you I'd replace the sound() call with a console.log, and see if you get the double output on the console.  Then you can be sure that its nothing to do with the sound api, rather your code or Raphael.

Comment: By adding in a tick counter (I am not sure whether it is in the right place...) I discovered that it is firing 3 times per sound played - does this have anything to do with it? Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wDwsW/2/

Comment: Ah, thank you! Clearly the callback is messed up, and the double or triple click comes from the three sound events getting off-sync as the animation gets tired. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, Raphael applies the animation to each of the three elements in the set, so the callback was being called three times. Thanks to @UpTheCreek and @StarBeamRainboxLabs.